# "with suppress" not working anymore in my Python 3 code?

Tags: python, xml

I'm processing the following XML from an API, which has a set of records like these:

```
<br.com.wine.sfweb.rest.controller.api.products.ProductDTO>
   <sku>18683</sku>
   <imageUrl>/renderImage.image?imageName=produtos/18683-01.png</imageUrl>
   <id>89117</id>
   <name>WineBox W Explorer Series</name>
   <type>Vinho</type>
   <attributes>
      <marketingCampaign>estoque-limitado</marketingCampaign>
      <country>Wine</country>
   </attributes>
   <ratings>
      <averageRating>4.19</averageRating>
      <numberOfRatings>21</numberOfRatings>
      <histogram>
         <entry>
            <string>3.0</string>
            <long>2</long>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>4.0</string>
            <long>9</long>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>1.0</string>
            <long>1</long>
         </entry>
         <entry>
            <string>5.0</string>
            <long>9</long>
         </entry>
      </histogram>
   </ratings>
   <rating>4.19</rating>
   <numberOfRatings>21</numberOfRatings>
   <available>true</available>
   <listPrice>402.00</listPrice>
   <salesPriceNonMember>402.00</salesPriceNonMember>
   <salesPriceClubMember>341.70</salesPriceClubMember>
</br.com.wine.sfweb.rest.controller.api.products.ProductDTO>
```

I do know that the children `<attributes>` is not always full, as per the documentation it is not required.

I've been processing all these records successfully (even the ones that are not there) by using, for example:

```
from contextlib import suppress

with suppress(AttributeError): tipoVinho = produtos.find('attributes/type').text
with suppress(AttributeError): paisVinho = produtos.find('attributes/country').text
```

So that if `<attributes><type>` is not there it just skips the Attribute error and moves on.

Now, out of the blue, whenever I fall into a missing attribute, I'm getting a `"name 'tipoVinho' is not defined"` error, like if the with suppress clause wasn't doing anything anymore.

I haven't upgraded anything, it just started to days ago (note that I had several cases where some attributes are missing, so this is pretty common).

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are suppressing the `AttributeError`, the assignment is cancelled. After all, the right-hand-side expression (`produtos.find().text`) did not return, **at all**. It did not even return `None`! Instead, it threw an Exception. This leads to cases where `tipoVinho` is undefined.

You will need to do special-casing for when the exception occurs, making `contextlib.suppress` not the right tool. Instead, just use exceptions:

```
try:
    tipoVinho = produtos.find('attributes/type').text
except AttributeError:
    tipVinho = None
```

Or set `tipVinho` to some default value before your possibly-failing assignment. Make sure to reset it in each loop iteration, if you do that!

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! I do see myself using suppress when I know something can throw an AttributeError, though when I'm suppressing this error aren't I just passing the error? Meaning, in this case, when I call tipoVinho = produtos.find() and it doesn't find the attribute, it would still create the variable and set it to NULL, wouldn't it?

That's my understanding because this was working (with the same XML attributes) up to a few days ago, but definitely initializing the variables inside the loop sounds plausible to me.